# MVC Newbie Question about Strongly-Typed Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I think this is a namespace issue, and the answer is probably dead simple, but I'm new at this MVC stuff.

I have multiple views named "Index." This was not a problem until I tried to create a new, strongly-typed view named "Index."

(For what its worth, I'm trying to follow along with the steps in the NerdDinner sample, but in VB instead of C#.)

When I added the strongly-typed view named "Index," the compiler threw this error:

> Base class 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of
>   System.Collections.Generic.List(Of
>   Models.User))' specified for class
>   'Index' cannot be different from the
>   base class 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage'
>   of one of its other partial types.

Can someone enlighten me on why this is happening, and what I can do to alleviate the problem?

Thanks in advance.

VIEW:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
         AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.vb" 
         Inherits="SampleSite.Index" %> 
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server"> 
</asp:Content>
```

Code Behind:

```
Imports System.Web.Mvc 
Imports System.Collections.Generic 

Partial Public Class Index Inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of List(Of SampleSite.Models.User)) 
End Class
```

Comment: Post the `Index` View, please

Comment: added it to the original post for you

Comment: This question resulted from my lack of understanding of the MVC way of doing web views (hence, the "newbie" in the question title). I was adding a view named "Index" into every view folder, rather than using the "Index" action on every controller.

Now that I know this, I no longer need to namespace every view. There is only one Index.aspx, and it is in the Home view folder.

Thanks to those who attempted to answer my stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say you have multiple "Index pages" then the problem is that all have the same namespace.
You have Index(a) derived from ViewPage and Index(b) derived from ViewPage of List(..), since the classes are declared partial and have equal namespaces the compiler tries to put them together in one class but is not possible since they don't inherit from the same base class.

Do this:
Index (a) -> Inherits="SampleSite.Index"
Index (b) -> Inherits="SampleSite.XXXXXXX.Index" and modify the code behind accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I would think you'll need to inherit from `ViewPage(Of List(Of SampleSite.Models.User))` in your page definition:

Does it work that way??

Your strongly-typed ViewPage must inherit from the "ViewPage(Of T)" basic generic type - where the T is the type of the data you want to display in your view page (the "view model").

Marc

Answer (score 0):

I figured it was just a namespace issue. I wrapped the offending Index class in a namespace like below and it solved the problem. Not sure if this is the correct way to solve this problem, but it works.

Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports System.Collections.Generic

**Namespace SampleSite**

```
Partial Public Class Index
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of List(Of Models.User))

End Class
```

**End Namespace**